# Starting supervisor programs as another user

Tags: php, docker, nginx, supervisord

I have a docker (`php:7-fpm-alpine`) container with [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) installed. It is added to a default installation by:

```
RUN apk add nginx composer php7-fpm php7-session supervisor && \
    ... ... ...
    cp supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor.d/conf.ini
```

Supervisor has its default config (didn't change it after installation), I have added my own config to append to it (`supervisord.conf`):

```
[program:php-fpm7]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/php-fpm.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/php-fpm.error.log

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=10
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/nginx.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/nginx.error.log
```

Now the original issue I have is that my Laravel app can't write to storage folder. I could `chmod 777` the folder recursively, and it works, but is not what I want.

So steps I took first is to `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/*` leaving permissions as is. This resolved nothing, still can't write.

Doing a `ps aux` revealed this:

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 {supervisord} /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration /etc/supervisord.conf
    8 root      0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: master process (/etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf)
    9 root      0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon off;
   10 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   11 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   12 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   13 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   14 nginx     0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www
   15 nginx     0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www
```

So `php-fpm` is running as `nginx` user (I've changed it's original config to replace user `nobody` to `nginx`). This did nothing good, as with this settings instead of `nobody` user, request returns 502 error.

Nginx master process is running as root, and worker processes as nginx.

This is a tad confusing as I am not sure which user is my web server using here? Root or nginx? Does it take the user from supervisor, nginx master or nginx worker?

I've tried changing supervisor to start as nginx user, but that fails as supervisor needs root access to create `pid`.

Reverting supervisor to root and adding `user=nginx` to `[program:nginx]` section made supervisor not start nginx at all.

How can I do the permissions here the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do , is to run both nginx and php-fpm as www-data:www-data

**step one**

add/edit this to your `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data www-data;
```

**step two**

add/edit `php-fpm.conf` and set user and group to www-data more info [here](https://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

I hope that will help you

Comment: Is this different from `www-data` user? I don't have `www` user on my Alpine installation

Comment: Sorry it was a typo :/

Comment: I type www because of your config : `15 nginx     0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www`

Comment: I did try this, and it is imperative I don't touch php-fpm user and leave them to nobody, otherwise I get nginx 502. However changing everything else to `www-data` does get response back, but it doesn't solve permission issue unfortunately

Comment: Sorry my bad. It works, and even works with nginx user. I was making a mistake of not changing `listen.owner` and `listen.group` of php-fpm config. Working good now, thanks!